# Error : Failed to obtain request token (Oauth)

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, passport.js

Unable to authenticate

I am trying npm passport-500px for Oauth 
I get this after requesting the Oauth route.

Unable to authenticate using the passport-500px-oauth strategy

```
InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain request token
       at Strategy.OAuthStrategy._createOAuthError (C:\Users\Sumant Bagade\Desktop\Facebook OAuth\node_modules\passport-500px\node_modules\passport-oauth\node_modules\passport-oauth1\lib\strategy.js:396:17)
       at C:\Users\Sumant Bagade\Desktop\Facebook OAuth\node_modules\passport-500px\node_modules\passport-oauth\node_modules\passport-oauth1\lib\strategy.js:244:41
       at C:\Users\Sumant Bagade\Desktop\Facebook OAuth\node_modules\passport-500px\node_modules\passport-oauth\node_modules\passport-oauth1\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth.js:543:17
       at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sumant Bagade\Desktop\Facebook OAuth\node_modules\passport-500px\node_modules\passport-oauth\node_modules\passport-oauth1\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth.js:421:9)
       at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
       at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:256:9)
       at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:169:7)
       at connectErrorNT (net.js:996:8)
```

I have tried-

1. localhost to 127.0.0.1
2. removing {secure: true  in middleware}
3. Setting up callback URL in app settings

Not sure whats wrong here.